# Any tips on masking user_id with friend request system?

Tags: php, encryption

I've a simple friend request system, where user clicks button which contains user_id of target user, this id and is passed to the function which creates request row in DB.

I don't want user to be able to request any user_id as a friend, just the ones I suggest.

So I need a way to mask user_id so malicious user doesn't start plugging in numbers and sending out requests with automatic tool.

I thought of a simple multiplication system. So I take user_id * really_long_number and than inside request function, I divide by that same number. Malicious user doesn't know the value of this really_long_number and thus doesn't know user_id.

so if:

```
user_id = 1
really_long_number = 12345678
key = 12345678
```

But I think this strategy is not the best, it can be really easily deduced by looking at enough numbers generated by system.

What do you suggest?

Comment: well, you could encrypt the IDs at least, but I suggest you to create a key for the request itself and save it in a table. Then you get the request key and you know the two IDs. Don't show any user ID on the client side.

Comment: Throw in base64_encoding with a custom alphabet.

Comment: @Brewal I do create request row in the friends table. But that has nothing to do with the question at hand, which is limit users possibility to hard request any user.

Comment: You misunderstood me... In your button, pass a well encrypted key for the request, not the user id. In other terms, have a `uniqkey` complex key for any user in your users table.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is a non-guessable uniq key for each user, and then pass it to your button instead of the user ID. You could have a field in your user table such as `myuniqkey` that will be filled with something like this at the creation of the user :

```
hash('sha512', uniqid().'myappsecretpass');
```

Comment: It won't change anything if you encode it after the request. You need to have an encrypted value within your http request. In this case your button : `<a href="/myrequestpage?userkey=theencryptedvalue">My button</a>`. You should not have decodable key.